# How do you manually tell Python which version to use in the script itself, across multiple operating systems?

Tags: python, linux, windows, version

I have Python 2.7 and 3.3 installed on Windows, and Python 2.7 and 3.2mu installed on Linux.
How would I write a Python script that is able to be used on both Windows and Linux, using version 2.X or 3.X?

I'm looking for maybe a few lines of code that will check to see what the current operating system is, and use Python 3.X in whatever directory it's in for the rest of the script.

I was thinking somewhere along the lines of:

```
if operating_system == Windows:
    run rest of script with C:\python_directory3.X\python
elif operating_system == Linux:
    run rest of script with /usr/bin/python3.X
```

Does code like this exist, or will I have to make a different script for both operating systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On UNIX systems, [Python commands should be named as prescribed in PEP-394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), so using a shebang is the best solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

As appropriate, at the top of your file.

Under Windows, it's a little less well defined. Since version 3.3, [a launcher](http://docs.python.org/dev/using/windows.html#launcher) should be included with Python, as described in [PEP-397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/). This, however, doesn't help older versions.

If you want to be sure under Windows, many people use py2exe, Cx_Freeze, or other similar tools to produce executables that include the interpreter. This may be a valid solution in some cases.

A good idea is to add a check to your code (checking the version of the interpreter), and give a clear, easy-to-understand message that they are using the wrong version of Python, perhaps with a link on how to solve that issue. This won't magically solve anything, but it means that if all else fails, the user gets a chance to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Since the OP *has* Python 3.3 installed on Windows, the launcher will take care of it just by using the shebang line, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not a Windows user, but from what I gather, yes. The only issue is that potentially, others don't have 3.3 installed, so it's not a complete solution. I'd argue coupling it with a decent error message when run in a 2.x interpreter is about as good as you can do though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the documents. Knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the OS in which the script is running using os module or sys module. Both shows different results, but similar:

```
import os
os.name #"posix" for linux "nt" for windows
# or 
import sys
sys.platform # "linux2" for linux
```

Comment: Just an aside, you can always get absolute path to the running Python executable with ``sys.executable``.